# Can a sunburn increase your resting heart rate?

Tags: cardiology, injury, cause-and-effect, sun-burn, forehead

I've been using a Fitbit to track my resting heartrate (among other things).  The value has consistently been in the 55-60 range for several weeks (most typical value over the past week or two is 57).  Over the past few days, however, it jumped to around 62; a 10% increase.

[image]

The bulk of the increase occurred 2 days ago, and the only thing I can think of that happened within that timeframe is that I got a mild sunburn (from kiteboarding, so primarily on my face/forehead from looking up at the sky all afternoon).  But correlation doesn't necessarily mean causation.  So my question is, can a sunburn lead to an increase in the body's resting heartrate?  And if so, why?

**Misc Notes**

I know a Fitbit isn't a medically accurate device, and that there's pending litigation over whether they're accurate *at all*.  However my anecdotal experience with my particular device is that it's quite accurate when at rest (during strenuous exercise the instantaneous readings can indeed be a bit funky and it can temporarily lose count altogether; although the average values that get logged to the dashboard seem reasonable despite the transient outliers/glitches).  So I don't think device inaccuracy/margin of error is the explanation.

Comment: Where you also outside and possibly more active than usual when you were getting the sunburn? How about warmer? Both of these easily raise your heart rate. Would you mind editing out " or other minor injury or illness" as that makes this overly broad.

Comment: @AtlLED - Maybe slightly more active than usual, but only for that one day.  Subsequent days were 'normal', and didn't cause the rate to drop back down.  And warmer, yes, it has been a fair bit warmer over the past week, particularly overnight and in the mornings.  Which is probably when I have the bulk of my 'at rest' time.

Comment: After a bad burn (pale skin plus Australian summer) my resting hearting on a Fitbit went from 49 up to 53 and down again over the course of the week while the burn subsided. (Daily exercise levels remained consistent, you don’t get to 49 without it being so, hydration was good, sleep temps stable due to Aircon etc). Def seems to be that inflammation due to the burn seems to raise it a few points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word: dehydration.

You spent a day out in the sun, exerting yourself, and probably didn't maintain your normal level of hydration. Consequently, you're mildly dehydrated (or, more properly, *hypohydrated*).

Dehydration means a lower blood volume, which in turn means your heart has to beat faster to move the same volume of blood. Consequently, your heart rate is mildly elevated until you restore your normal hydration levels.

### Summary of Findings [1](http://ksi.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1222/2015/04/Heart-Rate-and-Hydration-Template_New-Logo.pdf)

- Scientific  Definitions:  Hypohydration  is  the  steady state  condition  of  decreased  total  body water.  Dehydration  is  the  process  of  losing  body  water  (eg,  during exercise).
- Body  mass  losses  as  small  as  2%  have  been  shown  to  result 
  in  an  increase  in  cardiovascular  strain  and  subsequently 
  decrease performance  during  exercise. Exercise  in  the  heat 
  further  exacerbates  cardiovascular  strain,  thus  causing  further
  decrements  in  performance.
- **Results  have  shown  that  for  every  1%  decrease  in  body  mass 
  during  exercise  in  the  heat  there  is  an  increase  in  heart 
  rate  of  3.29 beats/min.  This  equates  to  an  increase  in  heart
  rate  of  10  beats/min  if an  athlete is  3%  dehydrated.**
- Exercise  at  a  fixed  and  variable  intensity  has  shown  an 
  increase in heart  rate  of  3.55  and  1.39  beats/min  respectively
  during  exercise  in the  heat.